# Facebook iframe Like button gives "Bootloader is not defined"

Tags: javascript, facebook, iframe

I'm following the directions to add a Facebook Like button to my site. How hard could it be? The directions look simple. Here is my HTML:

```
<iframe id="id39" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:450px; height:80px;" scrolling="no" class="likeButton component" src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3a%2f%2flocalhost%3a8080%2ftest%2f&amp;send=true&amp;layout=standard&amp;width=450&amp;show_faces=true&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;font&amp;height=80" guise:attributeHash="+yj/AWCw4TJREowYfJCNoaoNfZk="></iframe>
```

(Yes, I know I'm using localhost---how else am I supposed to test it?)

The button doesn't show up on Firefox 4 or IE9. Firebug shows me that stuff is getting loaded in the iframe. And I get a nice "Bootloader is not defined" error in the Bootloader.configurePage([]) that Facebook loads into the iframe. What's up?

Comment: The problem must be the "localhost" after all, even though I had read on other sites of developers using localhost for testing. I changed the URL to "www.example.com" and the Like button showed up---after a while waiting on facebook.com in the browser. Apparently Facebook contacts the site and gathers various metadata before showing the button, and if it can't access the site (e.g. localhost) it doesn't fail well.